# Please, explain for total beginner this .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some troubles understanding how to dynamically put together simple one language website. I would really appreciate if somebody could explain me in baby language what every part of the code below means:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)$

RewriteRule (.*)$ templates/index.php [L]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# Enable RewriteEngine to rewrite URL patterns
RewriteEngine On

# Every URI that not (! operator) ends with one of .php, .css, .js, .gif, .png, .jpg, .jpeg or .pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)$

# Will be redirected to templates/index.php
RewriteRule (.*)$ templates/index.php [L]

# Sample
# /foo/bar.php -> /foo/bar.php
# /foo/bar.html -> templates/index.php
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel dumber and not dumber at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Turns the rewrite engine on

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)$
```

Matches all requests which end *not* with .php, .css etc.

- `!` = negates the following expression ("matches not")
- `\.` = A single point (has to be escaped so it's taken literally. Without the backslash it would match every character)
- `(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)` = One of these options. `jpe?g` means the `e` is optional, so it matches `jpg` and `jpeg`
- `$` = the end of the request.

`RewriteRule (.*)$ templates/index.php [L]`

Redirects all request not matching the regular expression to `templates/index.php`. `[L]` means it's the last rule, so not other rules from this .htaccess get applied.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable RewriteEngine
2. RewriteCond defines when RewriteRule is started, in your cause it's checking file extensions (**if not** in this case, because of !)
3. When RewriteCond is true, request is redirected to templates/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess rewrites the URLs of the pages of your website.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Simply means that your Web Server, Apache, will now turn on his Rewrite Engine.

Then there is the Rewriting rule, which has a condition. First, the condition :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf)$
```

The condition is on the URL requested by the client. It means that if the said URL does not end in .php, .css, .js, .gif, .png, .pdf, .jpg, or .jpeg, the rule below will be applied.

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ templates/index.php [L]
```

This rules means that the end of the URL, which could be ".literally_anything" will be replaced by "templates/index.php"

The [L] means this is the last rewriting rule.

More explanations here : http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/